# Editor to open binary files?

Tags: encryption, gedit, binary

I have a binary file called `qkey` - when I try to open it with gedit, I get an error telling me that the file is in an unknown format.

Is this due to possible encryption? (it is a game stats file after all...)
Or is it simply that gedit can't open binary files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried a number of different applications to open binary files. The one that I've used and enjoyed the most is called `bless` and it is really easy to install. Simply open the terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `sudo apt-get install bless` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Note: You will have to enter your password, when you enter your password there will be no indicator on the screen, no asterisks, and the cursor will not move. This is normal behavior. After entering your password press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again and follow any additional instructions given.

As a hex editor, `bless` has lots of features and is actually surprisingly light. This should open your game file and allow you to edit it. I can't actually help with anything beyond that as I am not a gamer. However, it's in the repo and is easy enough to install without taking up much room or being overly complex.

You can read more and learn more about `bless` by clicking [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/bless/).

Comment: I'm a 2000 rep user - I know how to use the terminal... LoL **;)**

Comment: I'd assumed *you* knew but I was writing for posterity in case others came along behind you. I am working on making my answers more complete and, hopefully, able to last the ages (or at least a while). Sorry if it seemed like a slight - it was just for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `hexdump` to open a binary file.

```
hexdump -C qkey | more
```

or use vim with [the tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hex_dump)

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text seems to be more reliable than gedit in both supported file types and handling large buffers more easily.